# Disable warnings during cmake bulding

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

When there are some errors during building it's hard to find them in the list because there is also a lot of warnings

> 66 warnings and 7 errors generated.

How I hide warnings during building and show only errors?

[image]

Comment: Actually, you should fix those warnings rather than pretend not seeing them. But, each warning corresponds to a particular compiler option, you may find that compiler option to suppress your warnings accordingly.

Comment: @shizhen no I should not, it's source code of FFmpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you should fix the warnings rather than ignore them (a lot of them are really good at finding bugs, some not so much), but since you say this is not your code, probably best to just disable the warning.

You've trimmed the part of the log that has the part that names the warnings, but each of those lines will look something like:

```
foo.cpp:2:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

To silence that particular warning, add `-Wno-return-type` to your cflags.

Note that while you could silence *all* warnings to save yourself the effort of manyally curating this list, I strongly recommend doing them one by one so you know what you're ignoring. There are a handful of warnings that shouldn't be ignored even in third-party code. `-Wreturn-type`, for instance, is pointing out a block of code that Clang *will* do funny things with (it's undefined behavior). There are also important security warnings like `-Wstrlcpy-strlcat-size`:

```
#include <string.h>

void foo() {
    char bar[2];
    char baz[] = "baz";
    strlcpy(bar, baz, sizeof(baz));
}

foo.cpp:6:30: warning: size argument in 'strlcpy' call appears to be size of the source; expected the size of the destination [-Wstrlcpy-strlcat-size]
    strlcpy(bar, baz, sizeof(baz));
                      ~~~~~~~^~~~
```